# vba script created and running in windows7 32 bit does not work in windows10 64 bit

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, vba, 64-bit

I had created a billing format using VBA. It worked fine in Windows 7 32 bit, but does not work in Windows 10 64 bit system.

I am getting the error

> RUN-TIME ERROR '1004'
>   DOCUMENT NOT SAVED. THE DOCUMENT MAY BE OPEN, OR AN ERROR MAY HAVE BEEN ENCOUNTERED WHEN SAVING.

And this is my VB code:

```vb
Private Sub PDFBills()

    Dim flnm As String
    This.Range("E2:O50").Select
    flnm = "E:\BKTRADERS\TRADERBILLS\Bills_2019_20\BKT_19-20_" & ActiveSheet.Range("I8").Value & ".PDF"

    If Dir(flnm) <> "" Then

        Ans = MsgBox("File already exists.  Overwrite?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Overwrite?")
        If Ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    End If
    If IsFileOpen(flnm) Then
        MsgBox "File already IN USE / OPEN!"
    Else

        **Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=flnm, Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False**

    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Does `ActiveSheet.Range("I8").Value` contain any characters which would make the filename invalid? 2) You can remove the `& ".PDF"` when creating the filename because Excel will add it - and it will give an error if it is not happy with the filename extension. 3) Does the user account that the program is running under have permission to write to that directory?

Comment: Can you create a file in that directory with the same name **without VBA** (for example, using the Explorer)?

Comment: Do you have Excel 32-bit or Excel 64-bit installed?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment